# Mapkit Point Arrow Indicator in iOS Map

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mapkit

I use MapKit to view the map and put the annotations. I need an arrow which will point from blue dot to selected annotation with specified coordinates. When blue dot moving as user moving, the arrow will rotating and still pointing to the selected annotation in degree. It is not road navigation (like using MKPolyline) but just an arrow pointing to selected point.

Looks like I know how to share this image for more clear explanation:

[image: ht![tps://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3C_JRmFWyOBU0Z3OGFTOFFVUDQ/edit?usp=sharing][1]]

Comment: add the image to a share service and add the URL to the question

Comment: You know about mapkit and annotations, so what's the question here?

Comment: the question is to have that green arrow pointing to the selected annotation from current position (blue dot), and also counts the distance of annotations in KM..